# mysql - How to handle query search with special characters %(percent) and _(underscore)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 records in my database, **`Tom%Jerry`** and **`Ninja_Kids`**. One has a special character %(percent) and the other has _(underscore). I tried the following commands in mysql terminal.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME LIKE '%%%';
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME LIKE '%_%';
```

Both of the commands returned all the records.

How am I gonna make these return the record that has either `%` or `_`.

I know that `%` is used in mysql like a reserved word but what if there are cases that a record contains special characters mentioned above.

BTW, aside from the 2 do you know other special characters that don't behave normal?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `%` and `_`. The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html).

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME LIKE '%\%%';
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME LIKE '%\_%';
```

Comment: Thanks for citing the actual answer. Im gonna accept this one. Just waiting for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an escape character() before, like:-

```
select * from table where column like '\%\_' 


to match for string '%_'
```